# Using Up Arrow in Cygwin within command

Tags: cygwin

I just reinstalled Cygwin on my new PC, and I am having a problem with the up arrow. While at the regular Cygwin prompt, the up arrow works fine to scroll through the previous commands. However, on my old installation, I used to be able to use the up arrow inside of commands. In other words, if I ran java from the command line, using the up arrow would let me scroll through my previous inputs to java; or if I was using SQLPlus, up arrow would scroll through the previous inputs to SQLPlus. Does anyone know how to enable this?

I know rlwrap provides some similar functionality, but I'd love to have this working by default, and also I'm not sure that rlwrap will remember the inputs from previous executions of the command.

Comment: It could be the readline tool. Do you have that package installed?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I have readline installed.